How to pass value or variable outside of onAuthStateChanged?
I'm currently trying to get authenticated user's uid from google authentication for specific collection from "User" document. I'm using onAuthStateChanged is to prevent data went null after refreshing the webpage. The code is provided as below:
import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'

let UserUid = ""

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user != null) {
        UserUid = user.uid
    }
    else {
        console.log("User is null")
    }
})

const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "User", UserUid))

interface DataUser {
    FullName: string;
    Email: string;
    ContactNo: string;
    CountryCode: string;
    ICNO: string;
    HomeAddress: string;
    image: string;
    userType: UserType;
}

export const DataUser:DataUser = {
    FullName: docSnap.data()!["Name"],
    Email: docSnap.data()!["Email"],
    ContactNo: docSnap.data()!["Contact"],
    CountryCode: docSnap.data()!["CountryCode"],
    ICNO: docSnap.data()!["ICNO"],
    HomeAddress: docSnap.data()!["HomeAddress"],
    image: docSnap.data()!["Image"],
    userType: 0,
}

The error had occurred where UserUid in the last line shows that it was an empty string. It seems like the value did not pass to UserUid from onAuthStateChanged.
Is there anyways I can pass the value to UserUid?
I had tried using this.UserUid but it shows this was undefined.

You can declare and use the variable anywhere you want, but the problem is that you should only use it after you've set the value. This reads like a XY problem though. Can you edit your question to show how you're trying to use docSnap, and why you can't move that code into onAuthStateChanged?

This code is code in Database.ts and I was going to pass the object from docSnap to MainPage.vue.

onAuthStateChanged is asynchronous, and it will not wait for the callback to execute before moving on to getDoc.  As your code is written, UserUid is always going to be an empty string for the call to getDoc.  Some time later, the callback might happen when a user is signed in, but you have no guarantee how long that will take.

Thanks for the explanation on onAuthStateChanged, but if I put docSnap into onAuthStateChanged when I first login into the webpage, will the user be null? Cause from my understanding is that the onAuthStateChanged only will be executed after the webpage was refresh or reopen

Correct, when the page initially loads there is no current user yet (as Firebase needs to check with the server whether the credentials are still valid, and that takes time). Your code will need to handle this situation (e.g. by rendering a "loading..." message) and then execute the code that needs the UID once that is available, so by calling it from onAuthStateChanged.

When the page initially loads there is no current user yet, as Firebase needs to check with the server whether the credentials are still valid, and that takes time.
There is no way to make the main code on your page wait until that call has been completed. So instead, your code will need to handle this situation, for example by rendering a "loading..." message. Then when the user credentials have loaded, you can execute the code that needs the UID - so by calling it from onAuthStateChanged.

Does that means that I can't pass any value out of onAuthStateChanged where I can only execute the code where it needs the UID?

It's not about where you access it, but when you access it. The top-level code typically runs when the page loads, and at that point the UID isn't available yet from Firebase. --- To ensure the UID is available, you need to trigger that code from onAuthStateChanged. It's pretty common to have multiple auth state listeners in different parts of your app.

I have managed to solve my problem by passing the value into localStorage.[self-define_name]
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        localStorage.useruid = user.uid
    }
    else {
        console.log("User is Log Out")
    }
    
})

// useruid is log on the webpage even when the page is reloaded
console.log(localStorage.useruid)

const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "User", localStorage.useruid))

